# How to have else condition under range function in helm?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

Need to have a additional else condition under the "data" and "array" section of the range function, used in the below secretproviderclass helm template.

Its for picking common keyvault keys from the keyvault which doesn't have any release name prefix with them in addition to the keys which have specific release name prefix. Also it shouldn't make any repetition.

```yaml
spec:
  provider: azure
  secretObjects:
  - data:
      {{- range .Values.keyvault.secrets }}{{/* <-- only one range loop */}}
    - key: {{ . }}
      objectName: {{ $.Release.Name | upper }}-{{ . }} 
      {{- end }}      
    secretName: {{ $.Release.Name }}-kvsecret
    type: opaque
  parameters:
    usePodIdentity: "false"
    useVMManagedIdentity: "false"
    userAssignedIdentityID: ""
    keyvaultName: {{ .Values.keyvault.name | default "mykv01" }}    
    objects: |
      array:
        {{- range .Values.keyvault.secrets }}{{/* <-- only one range loop */}}        
        - |
          objectName: {{ $.Release.Name | upper }}-{{ . }}
          objectType: secret
        {{- end }}
    tenantId: {{ .Values.keyvault.tenantid }}
{{- end }}
{{- end -}}
```

values.yaml

```yaml
  keyvault:
    enabled: true
    name: myappscommonkv01
    secrets:
    - MY-SECRET-1      ######## secret specific for AppA
    - MY-SECRET-2      ######## secret specific for AppA
    - COMMON-SECRET-1  ######## secret Common  for AppA & AppB
    - COMMON-SECRET-2  ######## secret Common  for AppA & AppB
```

Comment: What would you want an `else` block to do?  In the example at the end, do any of the `secrets:` names match the chart's names; how should the chart know whether it's "common"?  I'm guessing, if something is a "common secret", then you want to omit the `$.Release.Name | upper` prefix in both of the places it appears?

Comment: yes, we need a solution, which can be used for picking both keys from the keyvault, where its prefixed with reelasename as well as the keys without releasename prefix. For ex: <ReleaseName>-AZURE-TENANT-ID secret (if present) pick the key and secret from the keyvault for that and map to <ReleaseName>-AZURE-TENANT-ID.
If previous was not present, AZURE-TENANT-ID secret (if present) mapped to AZURE_TENANT_ID e.
If none of the above were present then it should fail.

Comment: If you need to make a call to an external service to determine which name to use, I don't think this is something Helm is capable of doing.  You'd need to split this list into two lists, or somehow annotate each item with whether it needs to be prefixed or not.

Comment: N.. Its secretprovider class template to mount the keys from the keyvault. we already have the secrets created in kv and, need to fetch the values using this. The exact scenario is explained as part of this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76142193/helm-template-with-multiple-filter-for-key-values

Comment: How is this question different from that one; they seem to have very similar code and configuration?  At the time Helm renders the template, when Helm sees the name `SOME-STRING`, how should it know whether to add the prefix?